# vector serialization in mapreduce

Tags: java, serialization, vector, mapreduce

How do I serialize Vector in mapreduce.Below is my code where Adjacent_nodes is the vector to be written and read from Data streammers

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {       
    VID=in.readLong();
    Adjacent_nodes=in.read<????>();
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {      
    out.writeLong(VID); 
    out.write<???>(Adjacent_nodes);     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {       
    VID=in.readLong();
    long vector_size=in.readLong();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        Adjacent.addElement(in.readLong());
    }
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {      
    out.writeLong(VID); 
    out.writeLong(Adjacent_nodes.size());
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        out.writeLong(Adjacent.get(i));
}
```